# AJAX returning current page when trying to execute separate PHP query

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax, session

Okay so, I'm a bit stuck... Here's my problem. So, what I'm trying to achieve is I have a JS calendar and what I want it to do is when I click on a date, it fetches the times available for that day and displays it and then changes depending on what day you click on WITHOUT refreshing the page. Now, looking around, the only way I can seem to do this is with AJAX (suggestions welcome) although I have never touched AJAX before so have no idea what I'm doing here.

So I've currently got my .HTACCESS files setup on my webserver to use dynamic subdomains.

It's sort of like a multi-step form, and I'm collecting data in the SESSION as I go. Now what I'm guessing the way to do is here, to send a AJAX query with a JS variable with the date and then that runs an SQL query and gets the times and displays them. Here's what I have so far.

```
<a href="#" id="clickme">Update Session</a>

<div class="output"><?PHP echo $_SESSION["outputTimes"]; ?></div>

<script>
  $("#clickme").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'data.php',
        data: { date: '2020-07-04'},
        success:function(response){
           alert(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

data.php

```
<?php

 //Start Session
 session_start();

 //Include Database Config
 include ("config.php");

 //POST
 $requestDate = $_POST["date"];

 //Define SQL Query
 $app_get_sql = "SELECT * FROM cc_av WHERE date=$requestDate";

 //Run Query
 if($result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $app_get_sql)){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $_SESSION["outputTimes"] = '<li>'.$row["time"].'</li>';
    }
 }

?>
```

Currently, when I run this, I get the response in the alert() as the current code of the page I'm on. Hence why I noted about my HTACCESS although I can include() it just fine using the same root. Also, from the results of the data.php, how would I output the code sort of update what would be there at the moment.

Here's what I'm trying to create...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bgxSUxN6j2IOZcQBuAOo-PeCsuRgdmZ-/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're not echoing anything to the output buffer ..?

Comment: @Teemu What do you mean?

Comment: You're not putting anything to the output buffer which would be send as a response (i.e. there's no `echo` or `print` ...), you're just setting a value to the same session variable multiple times, overriding it again and again ...

Comment: @Teemu Where would I implement this? I've echoed the session["outputTimes"] in the HTML?

Comment: In the provided code you haven't any echo, you've just set a session variable. Notice also what Dharman has said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've managed to work out what was going wrong. Because my HTACCESS file is creating SubDomains, it was also redirecting the Paths so in the AJAX code I used a URL to the code instead and then added a header to my PHP code on the file that needed to be requested.

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (URL NEEDING TO BE REQUESTED)");
```

Final AJAX Code

```
    var scriptString = 'THISISMYSTRING';
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      method: 'get',
      url: '(URL)/data.php',
      data: {
        'myString': scriptString,
        'ajax': true
      },
      success: function(data) {
        $('#data').text(data);
      }
    });
});
```